# When does the consumer commit offset?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka-2.2.7-RELEASE. I'm using @KafkaListener to create my consumer.

I've set enable.auto.commit to true and auto.commit.interval.ms to 10,000 (i.e., 10 sec). Now my question is - does the consumer the commit offset for each record or does it commit and advance the offset by the no of records it consumed during the 10 sec ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We generally recommend not using `auto.commit.enabled=true`; letting the container do the commits with `BATCH` or `RECORD` `AckMode`s is more deterministic (before the next `poll()` or after each record is processed, respectively).

With version 2.3, we disable auto commit by default (unless it is explicitly set in the config).

With auto commit, my understanding is the commits will happen during a `poll()` if the interval has elapsed since a previous poll. It will commit the latest offset for each partition that have been previously processed since the last commit.

Comment: Does it mean, if we get 100 records when it first polled and the consumer was able to process only 80 records during the 10 sec time, does it commit and advance the offset by 80 and the remaining 20 messages are lost?

Comment: No; we don't call `poll()` again until all 100 records are processed; if it takes, say, 6 seconds to process all 100, the offsets for the first 100 won't be committed until the second 100 are processed. If it takes 20 seconds, the offsets will be committed on the next poll(). As I said, I prefer to use the more deterministic operation of the listener container. With `AckMode.BATCH` the offsets will always be committed when done, regardless of how long it takes.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'm wondering if spring-kafka has any listener if I want to log the events when the consumer is committing the offset

Comment: Kafka itself provides `ConsumerInterceptor` which is called when offsets are committed (either automatically or by the container). Implement the interface and use `ConsumerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG` to tell Kafka about it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.